# Using CreateFile to check exclusive write access

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, createfile

I need to check for exclusive write access of a file. I put in this code.

```
HANDLE fileH = CreateFile(filePath,
            GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
            0, // For Exclusive access
            0,
            OPEN_EXISTING,
            FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
            NULL);

if (fileH != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    // We have exclusive write access.
    CloseHandle(fileH);
}
else {
    // No exclusive write access.
}
```

Even for files which are open in shared read mode somewhere else, this is resulting in files getting opened. Though this is the result I wanted, but is this behavior of CreateFile API correct? Or should I only specify GENERIC_WRITE, instead of (GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE)?

Comment: With reference to the sample code: `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` means that the `CreateFile` operation failed.  If you are checking for exclusive write access, you should test for: `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` and  `GetLastError() == ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION`.  Otherwise the sample code could generate a false positive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want write access, then you may as well only specify `GENERIC_WRITE`.

Since you specify that you want exclusive access, that call will fail if there is another handle to the file open. You say that the function call is succeeding when another handle exists with `FILE_SHARE_READ` share mode. But you are mistaken. In that scenario, the call to `CreateFile` in your question fails.

---

According to the comments it sounds like you want to have the file open for exclusive access, concurrent with other parties having the file open. That is not possible. Exclusive means to the exclusion of all others. When you have a file open exclusively that means that yours is the one and only open handle to that file.

Comment: I checked again and I am not mistaken. - CreateFile called as above is not failing when file is open in another instance of app in shared read mode. Its Windows 8.1.
I would check behavior on Windows 7, or first opening in shared read mode in same instance of app.

Comment: What you said is true. When another file handle exists the call to CreateFile for exclusive access does fail. The handle opened for read-only mode was closed and hence I got the wrong impression.
What is the correct way to check for exclusive write access even though the file is open in shared read-only mode elsewhere?

Comment: Call CreateFile asking for whatever share mode you need. If that call succeeds, you are good to go.

Comment: Let me rephrase: Isn't it possible to get an exclusive Write access if  someone is having shared read access?

Comment: No. Exclusive means, well, exclusive. To the exclusion of all others.

Comment: Well then its doesn't matter if I put GENERIC_WRITE or (GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE) in call as in my question.

Comment: The former allows the system to find any programming mistakes where you erroneously read